# not sure if i solved this nested conditionals exercise in #python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on this exercise and since I self study i need someone to help me out with this.
I'm not sure if I've solved this correctly.
Primarily because i don't think I'm meant to be getting "True" or "False" as an output when i run the code.
what am I missing here ?

My code:

```
Check if word starts with "pre"
Check if word .isalpha()
if all checks pass: return True
if any checks fail: return False
Test
    get input using the directions: enter a word that starts with "pre":
    call pre_word() with the input string
    test if return value is False and print message explaining not a "pre" word
    else print message explaining is a valid "pre" word

def pre_word (word):

    if word.startswith("pre"):
        if word.isalpha():
            print ("Valid")
            return True
    else:
        print ("not valid")
        return False




print (pre_word (input("enter a word that starts with \"pre\": ")))
```

thanks in advance for any help or tips you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You're `print`ing `"Valid"` and `"Not Valid"` but you're returning the boolean values `True` and `False`, which are being printed in the end.

This code should work:

```
def pre_word (word):

    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha():
        return "Valid"
    return "Not Valid"

print (pre_word (input("enter a word that starts with \"pre\": ")))
```

Essentially, I amended the your `return` values to strings and cleaned your code up a bit. I used the `and` operator and removed the second `if` condition.

**In case you're wondering why there's no `else` condition:**

If the two conditions are `True`, your function will return "Valid". However, it won't go to the next line as it's already returned a value. If the two conditions are false, the `return "Not Valid" line will run.

Comment: shouldn't there be an "else" between the 2 returns ? also, i was getting a syntax error until i removed the 2nd if...?